# Is the Amazon EC2 instance id will be reused?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Today lots of peoples/developers are using VM's in EC2, so keeping in this mind there are lots of VM's were getting created and deleted every day.

Also, EC2 allocates an ID (auto-generated) to each instance in the cloud at the time of VM creation.

So, Is there any chance that this ID gets reused(repeated) considering this same ID was assigned to an instance but now that instance got deleted?

And Is this ID will be unique globally or per user??

Thanks

Comment: yup context is same but both ids have the different format, that why I have posted different questions.

Comment: It struck me as off, a new user posting a copy&paste question, that's why I flagged it. Teachers would say "lack of effort" I expected a bot.

Comment: Please check this question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/58401/is-the-amazon-ec2-instance-id-unique-forever/
In comments it's discussed that ids are not unique globally but rather per user.

Comment: thanks but that thread is too old, Amazon has revised their instance ID structure in between this years.

Answer (score 0):

I have talked with EC2 support and here is the reply:

"Once a resource has been assigned an ID (long or short), that ID will never change. Each ID is unique and will never be reused."

So I guess this is an answer to my question.

Thanks.